# Is there a way to get the selected item as first item in carousel?

Tags: javascript, angular

Ok let me change my question how to get the selected item as first item in carousel? This is my code. where output images is the loop to get the images to display in carousel. where carouselimage is the boolean variable to display carousel.

```
 if (this.window.IndustryXCarousel && this.outputimages && this.outputimages?.length >= 0 && this.isCarouselImage) {
  const outputModalCarousel = document.getElementsByClassName("output-modal-carousel");
  Array.prototype.map.call(outputModalCarousel, (outputCaro: any) => {
    const parent = outputCaro.closest(".-modal");
    let parentStyle = window.getComputedStyle(parent, null).display;
    if (parentStyle == "block") {
      let IndustryXCarousel = window.IndustryXCarousel;
      let outputObj = null;
      console.log(outputObj)
      outputObj = new IndustryXCarousel(outputCaro, {
        items: 3,
        firstItemFixed: false,
        arrows: true,
        dots: false,
        leftArrow: `<i class="icon-chevron-left"></i>`,
        rightArrow: `<i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>`,
        margin: 40,
        responsive: [
          {
            maxWidth: 1500,
            items: 1,
          },
          {
            maxWidth: 1250,
            items: 1,
          },
          {
            maxWidth: 600,
            items: 1,
          },
        ],
      });
    }

  });
  this.isCarouselImage = false;
}
```

Comment: please share sample code

Comment: simply read the ngFor documentation: https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do `let i = index` in the directive params and thus you will know the index

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
   <button (click)="slideTo((i + 1)%items.length)">next</button>
   ....
```

Comment: I will get the index but that's not the problem. I need to get the clicked image displayed in popup first and then i can use carousel icon to move next or previous. See my sample code please